# How to calculator cost per month in AWS SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I want to use nodejs to calculate the cost and billing each month for my users in AWS.

However, I could not find SDK support to get cost and billing information each month.

[image: billing]

Answer (score 1):

There are some node.js sdk available under `Budgets` section. See if you can use these api's to cater to your needs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Budgets.html

Comment: Thank Madhukar Mohanraju

Answer (score 0):

AWS supports programmatic access to billing data. Basically you assign an S3 bucket and then parse the CSV log files that billing generates.

[Programmatic Access to AWS Billing Data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/)

[API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/api-reference.html)